# Does fold tightness correlate to deformation intensity?

Tags: petrology, tectonics, structural-geology

I'm studying a migmatite with two overprinting fold structures. The first (Dn+1) is tight and the second (Dn+2) is gentle. Would it be fair to assume that, since Dn+1's tightness is, well, tighter, then the deviatoric stress applied on it is more intense, or is the correlation tightness-deformation intensity not actually that trustworthy? I'd be grateful if you could link some papers on the subject.

I'd like to use that as an evidence to the event leading to Dn+1 being closer to the maximum pressure the rock was put under.

Thanks in advance!